# Selecting from a Julia Dataframe using the `contains` function

Tags: julia

I have a DataFrame `df` with a column named "cond". One of the values in this column is "aer". To select all the rows with cond == "aer", this code works:

```
select(:(cond .== "aer"), df)
```

But this doesn't

```
select(:(contains(["aer"],cond)), df)
```

It fails with the error:

> ERROR: all SubDataFrame indices must be > 0
>   in SubDataFrame at /Users/seanmackesey/.julia/DataFrames/src/dataframe.jl:1007
>   in sub at /Users/seanmackesey/.julia/DataFrames/src/dataframe.jl:1020
>   in select at /Users/seanmackesey/.julia/DataFrames/src/dataframe.jl:1031

I looked at the source but fail to understand what's going on here. What are the general limitations on what I can put in expression predicates like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `contain` isn't a vectorized operation:

```
julia> contains(["aer"], ["aer", "aer", "abr"])
false
```

This probably means that it's not generating valid indices.

In general, the family of expressions that should work in `select` are those that generate a vector of indices. There are a few broken cases, but I believe the problem in this case is just that the predicate isn't producing useful indices.

Comment: I think there is an error contain -> contains. Apparently I can not edit your answer because the fix is less than 6 characters.

Comment: @JohnMylesWhite I see-- is there a simple way to take any expression that would return true/false for each row and wrap it so that it can return a vector of indices? I tried doing `@vectorize_2arg Any contains` but this did not work.